# Topological Hopf algebras and lifts of Spf.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, category-theory

There is an 1-1 correspondence between co-(abelian group) objects in the category of commutative $k$-algebras, $\mathbf{Alg}_k$ (i.e. bicommutative Hopf algebras) and lifts of the the functor they represent $\mbox{Spec}_k(H) \colon \mathbf{Alg_k} \to \mathbf{Set}$ to a functor $\mathbf{Alg_k} \to \mathbf{Ab}$.

Explicitly, if $H$ is a bicommutative Hopf algebra, then $\mbox{Spec}_k(H) \colon \mathbf{Alg_k} \to \mathbf{Set}$ lifts to a functor $\mathbf{Alg_k} \to \mathbf{Ab}$. Conversely, if $H$ is a $k$-algebra, then a lift of the functor $\mbox{Spec}_k(H)$ to a functor $\mathbf{Alg_k} \to \mathbf{Ab}$ induces a the structure of a Hopf algebra on $H$.

I was wondering whether this result passes to the world of formal schemes. As an example, if $H$ is a topological Hopf algebra, that is a Hopf algebra, together with Hopf ideals $J$ inducing the topology, then the functor $\mbox{Spf}(H) = \varinjlim \mathbf{Alg}_k(H/J, -) \colon \mathbf{Alg}_k \to \mathbf{Set}$ lifts to a functor $\mathbf{Alg_k} \to \mathbf{Ab}$. Indeed, $H/J$ is a Hopf algebra for each $J$ and thus $\mathbf{Alg}_k(H/J, -) \colon \mathbf{Alg}_k \to \mathbf{Ab}$, since the direct limit of abelian groups is an abelian group, the result follows.

However, the converse result does not seem to hold. Namely if $H$ is a topological algebra filtered by ideals $J$ such that $\mbox{Spf}(H)$ lifts to a functor $\mathbf{Alg_k} \to \mathbf{Ab}$, there seems to be no reason that each $J$ should be a Hopf ideal. Indeed, even if $\mathbf{Alg}_k(H/J, X)$ is a set, we may still have $\varinjlim \mathbf{Alg}_k(H/J, X)$ being a group.

What extra conditions do we need on the lift of the functor $\mbox{Spf}(H)$ for this result to be true? I.e. under what conditions is a lift of the functor $\mbox{Spf}(H)$ to $\mathbf{Alg_k} \to \mathbf{Ab}$ equivalent to the structure of a topological Hopf algebra on $H$?

Answer (score 0):

I've not completely satisfactorily answered the question, but here is partial answer.

The category of solid formal schemes is anti-equivalent to the category of complete topological algebras. Hence the category of solid formal group schemes (group objects in solid formal schemes) is anti-equivalent to the category of complete topological Hopf algebras. Thus a lift of $\Spf(H)$ is the same as the structure of a complete topological Hopf algebra. For the explicit construction of $H$ as a topological Hopf algebra, I believe you have to do some fiddly replacements of the filtration.